# Using Findstr to search for drive letter

Tags: batch

I tried to use below script to locate the correct drive letter (starting from Drive C) containing the folder/files but not able to do so. Please help to see where went wrong. Picture with error is attached also. Thanks.

```
@For /F "Delims=: " %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\mountvol.exe ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IR "[C-Z]:\\"') Do @(
If Exist "%%G:\Sources\SxS\." (
%SystemRoot%\System32\Dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:"netfx3" /All /LimitAccess /Source:"%%G:\Sources\SxS" /NoRestart
) 
)

echo %errorlevel%
If errorlevel 0 (echo Framework Updated) else (Echo No Source Files are Found)

Pause
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, `mountvol` without any parameter doesn't do anything useful. What's your goal?

Comment: My goal is to run this DISM command but I want the script to tell if it can find the source files before running, if no files are found then display error message.

Comment: The DISM command which I want to run is     %SystemRoot%\System32\Dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:"netfx3" /All /LimitAccess /Source:"%%G:\Sources\SxS" /NoRestart

Comment: Why not use the new (since Windows 2000) `if %errorlevel% EQ 0` ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set mydrive=NOT_FOUND
for /f "skip=1" %%G in ('wmic logicaldisk get name') do (
    if exist "%%G\Sources\SxS" set mydrive=%%G
    )
echo drive is %mydrive%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to list all the disks, but `mountvol` does not do that.

The command you want is `wmic` with one of the following :

```
wmic logicaldisk get name
wmic logicaldisk get caption
```

Comment: Thanks. Your script is not a workable resolution to my needs. I need  the code to find the source drive to implement the DISM function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this simple FOR loop.

```
for %%G in ( C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z ) do (
    if /i exist ”%%G:\sources\sxs\.” (
        rem your command
        goto :success
    )
)
:success 
rem ^^^ remember to add a success label to exit the loop when the letter is found
rem your post-loop commands
```

Hope this helps! (Also, I didn't understand what you wanted to do with the `echo %errorlevel%` and `if %errorlevel%==0` commands, if you can explain maybe I can help you to include those ones in the script since I'm not sure what you want to do with them.)

Comment: Your suggestion works and I am applying it to my batch. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have another question and looking for resolution. Do you think you can help me out ? https://superuser.com/questions/1759001/get-full-path-of-a-file-with-partial-name/1759004?noredirect=1#comment2733920_1759004

Comment: Happy that you made it! Of course I can help you!

Comment: @VB88 I left an answer on the question you gave me.

Comment: Hi, I'm here just to remind you to close this answer as completed.