# Get full path of a file with partial name

Tags: batch

I want to achieve the full path of a file with just partial name of the file name. The below batch script does not show any result.
Full path is "D:\Site Information\HBOC\Cen As Install Files\CenASintstall_4.0(DS-70-026-W).exe"

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p "pc=Enter Computer Name : "

:opt1 -not workable
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "D:\Site Information" /s /b ^| findstr "(%pc%).exe"') do echo %%~dpa

:opt2 -not workable
for /f "tokens=* delims=\" %%a in ('dir "D:\Site Information" /s /b ^| findstr "(%pc%).exe"') do echo %%~dpa
Pause
```

REVISION 1
I use several options to get the results. Here is my script and screenshot. I also want to include the filename in the search result. What should be added to the script ?!
Full path is "D:\Site Information\HBOC\Cen As Install Files\CenASintstall_4.0(DS-70-026-W).exe"

```
:opt1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "D:\Site Information" /s /b ^| find "(%pc%).exe"') do echo "Option1 is %%~dpa"
REM  D:\Site Information\HBOC\Cen As Install Files\

:opt2
for /f "tokens=* delims=\" %%a in ('dir "D:\Site Information" /s /b ^| findstr "(%pc%).exe"') do echo "Option2 is %%~dpa"
REM  D:\Site Information\HBOC\Cen As Install Files\

:opt3
for /f %%a in ('dir "D:\Site Information" /s /b ^| find "CenASintstall_4.0(%pc%).exe"') do echo "Option3 is %%~dpa"    
REM Result is D:\

:opt3A
for /f %%a in ('dir "D:\Site Information" /s /b ^| find "(%pc%).exe"') do echo "Option3A is %%~dpa"    
REM Result is D:\


:opt4
for /f "tokens=* delims=\" %%a in ('dir "D:\Site Information" /s /b ^| find "(%pc%).exe"') do echo "Option4 is %%~dpa"
REM  D:\Site Information\HBOC\Cen As Install Files\

:opt5
for /f "tokens=* delims=\" %%a in ('dir "D:\Site Information" /s /b ^| findstr "(%pc%).exe"') do echo "Option5 is %%~dpa"
REM  D:\Site Information\HBOC\Cen As Install Files\
    
:opt6
for /f "tokens=* delims=\" %%a in ('dir "D:\Site Information" /s /b ^| findstr "CenASintstall_4.0(%pc%).exe"') do echo "Option6 is %%~dpa"
REM  D:\Site Information\HBOC\Cen As Install Files\
```

[image]

REVISION 2

Revised script

```
for /f %%a in ('dir "D:\Site Information" /s /b ^| find "CenASintstall_4.0(%pc%)"') do echo "Option3B is %%~dpa%%~a"
```

[image]

REVISION 3

```
set user=USER
set /p "pc=Enter Computer Name : " 
goto pcname


:pcname
REM Locate the Drive contains the folder-"Site Information"
set mydrive=NOT_FOUND
for /f "skip=1" %%G in ('wmic logicaldisk get name') do (
    if exist "%%G\Site Information" set mydrive=%%G
    )
echo Possible USB Drive is %mydrive%  
if %mydrive%==NOT_FOUND (goto nas) else (goto check)
   

:check
REM Locate the executable file with full path
set pathdrive=NOT_FOUND
for /f "tokens=* delims=\" %%a in ('dir "%mydrive%" /s /b ^| find /i "(%pc%).exe"') do set "pathdrive=%%~dpnxa"
 echo. The file path is %pathdrive%
if "%pathdrive%"=="NOT_FOUND" (goto nas) else (goto extract)
```

SCREENSHOT 4

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your script that could be causing it not to work as expected.

First, in the for loop, you are using findstr to search for the file name that contains the computer name entered by the user. However, findstr only searches for a string within a file, it does not search for file names. Instead, you can use the find command to search for the file name.

Here is an example of how you can modify your script to search for the file with the partial name and print the full path:

```
    @echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p "pc=Enter Computer Name : "

for /f %%a in ('dir "D:\Site Information" /s /b ^| find "CenASintstall_4.0(%pc%)"') do echo %%~dpa
```

This script will search for a file in the directory "D:\Site Information" and all of its subdirectories that has a name containing the string "CenASintstall_4.0" followed by the computer name entered by the user. If a file is found, it will print the full path of the file.

Edit 1
If you also want to include the file name you can use this :

```
@echo off
set /p "pc=Enter computer name: "
for /f %a in ('dir "D:\Site Information" /s /b ^| find "CenASintstall_4.0(%pc%)"') do echo %~dpa%%~a
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Your script only show the directory not full path. See my REVIISION 1. How can I include the full filename in the search result ?! Please help.

Comment: Hi @VB88 to include the file name in the search result, you can simply add the %%~a variable to the echo statement. This expands to the name of the file with the extension.

`@echo off
set /p "pc=Enter computer name: "
for /f %a in ('dir "D:\Site Information" /s /b ^| find "CenASintstall_4.0(%pc%)"') do echo %~dpa%%~a ` this will search for a file in the "D:\Site Information" directory and its subdirectories that contains the input, and print the full path of the file, including the file name.
I have also updated my answer.

Comment: I used your new script to test but it is the same result. See my REVISION 2. Still does not show the full path with file name !?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this:

```
for /R "D:\Site Information" %%A in ("CenASinstall*.exe") do (echo Found, path is %%A)
```

And if you want to search for the executables that contain the computer name, try with:

```
for /R "D:\Site Information" %%A in ("CenASinstall*(%computername%).exe") do (echo Found, path is %%A)
```

Lemme know if it works! [sorry if this is not what you're looking for but I first need to have 50 reputations to leave comments & ask for clarifications :( ]

EDIT: Just tried them, they seem to work [see screenshots]

[image: screenshot]

I created the same folder tree and it seems OK.

Leave a comment if you don't understand something or if I explained myself badly (which I surely did lol).

**Side notes**

> You may be wondering why in the second command I did `("CenASinstall*(%computername%).exe")` instead of simply doing `("CenASinstall_4.0(%computername%).exe")`: I put the star because the FOR /R command works only if the "target filename" has 1 or more blank characters. By adding the star you're saying that everything between "CenASinstall" and "(%computername%).exe" needs to be retrieved. By leaving a blank portion of the filename (in this case it is the version number) you're basically asking FOR to retrieve it. (With this little trick you can make the command work. And most importantly, you will also achieve the job of scanning only through those filenames that contain both the "CenASinstall" string and the name of the computer.)

> You don't necessarily need to ask the user the computer name with the `set /p pc=enter the name` command, since it is already stored in the `%computername%` variable. But if you need it, ask the computer name anyway and replace the `%computername%` variable with the `%pc%` one.

> The first command is going to search through all the filenames containing the "CenASinstall" string, the second command is going to search only through all the filenames containing both the "CenASinstall" string and the name of the computer.

> In the tree I created to try the commands I completely forgot to add caps and other things, but I edited the commands and fixed everything.

> The full path of the executable is stored in `%%A` and you can retrieve it by doing `echo %%A` or, to make it last forever, `echo %%A>>somefilename.txt`.

Comment: Hi, I found I cannot use FOR /R in this case cos there are same file name with different extensions in subdirectories. Only FOR /F is workable. See my REVISION 3.  However I found another issue that my script in REVISION  3 does not extract the latest file with (%pc%)(2).exe. See my SCREENSHOT 4 !!

Comment: If there are more than 1 file named “CenASinstall.exe” but with a different file extension you can decide to filter the results and make it show only the file you’re looking for. If you can tell me what these file are named and where in the directory tree they are, I can do some tries for you and adjust the command according to your need.

Comment: I created another question, please see if you can help. Thanks. https://superuser.com/questions/1759966/finding-all-possible-results-using-for-and-find-findstr

Comment: Sure, I'll check it out now.