# Finding all possible results using FOR and find /findstr

Tags: batch

I use below batch script to find the file with .exe extension. However some file name has two names - **CenASintstall_4.0(DS-15-103-W).exe** and **CenASintstall_4.0(DS-15-103-W) (2).exe**  (not all files have two file names co-existing)

How can I modify my code to get the one with (2) if it does. See my batch script and screenshot for easy understanding.

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

:scan
Echo Auto-Detect Source
set pc=DS-15-103-W
goto pcname


:pcname
REM Locate the Drive contains the folder-"Site Information"
set mydrive=NOT_FOUND
for /f "skip=1" %%G in ('wmic logicaldisk get name') do (
    if exist "%%G\Site Information" set mydrive=%%G
    )
echo Possible USB Drive is %mydrive%  
if %mydrive%==NOT_FOUND (goto nas) else (goto check)


:check
REM Locate the executable file with full path
set pathdrive=NOT_FOUND
for /f "tokens=* delims=\" %%a in ('dir "%mydrive%" /s /b ^| find /i "(%pc%).exe"') do set "pathdrive=%%~dpnxa"
echo. The file path is %pathdrive%
if "%pathdrive%"=="NOT_FOUND" (goto nas) else (goto extract)


:extract
    REM Run file extraction
    "%pathdrive%" /s /x /b" %systemdrive% /v" /qn"
    echo %errorlevel%
    pause
```

[image]
[image]

If I change the for /f.. to

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=\" %%a in ('dir "%mydrive%" /s /b ^| find /i "(%pc%)(2).exe"') do set "pathdrive=%%~dpnxa"
```

It cannot search that file !
[image]

Screenshot 4

[image]

Comment: You (fine person) could really benefit by a more powerful medium to entertain your talents.  I might suggest powershell, c#, or other to go down this path.  Batch (which I love) is not very good at simply parsing strings and you end up using hacky uncommon sense of other tools to deal with.  The 1 answer I already see is not wrong.  Using this method to accomplish this goal might be.

Comment: I am not good at powershell to rewrite my whole script and I am not sure where to put the caret ^ . Any help !

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
for /R "D:\Site Information" %%A in ("CenASinstall*(2).exe") do (echo Found, path is %%A)
```

and, if you need to search for those files containing the computer name in their filename, with this:

```
for /R "D:\Site Information" %%A in ("CenASinstall_4.0(%computername%)*.exe") do (echo Found, path is %%A)
```

Lemme know if this modified version of the command works.

EDIT: I updated the command, and everything seems working perfectly.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I used the second option but it does not work either.

Comment: I used the second option but it did not work out. See my screenshot 4. And I tried to add wildcard but it did not work either - for /r "tokens=* delims=\" %%a in ('dir "%mydrive%" /s /b ^| find /i "*%pc%*.exe"') do set "pathdrive=%%~dpnxa"

Comment: Found the problem. Thanks for telling me, fixing right now.

Comment: @VB88 FOR /R does not work like FOR /F, and it doesn’t accept arguments such as “tokens, skip, delims” because it is meant to do operations on files.

Comment: @VB88 I updated the command, lemme know if this time it works for you or not.
If not, please post a screenshot of the results and I'll try to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off && Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

:scan
echo/Auto-Detect Source
set "_pc=DS-15-103-W"
set "_my_drive=NOT_FOUND"
set "_file_path=NOT_FOUND"

:pcname
for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^<^> %%G in (
    `wmic logicaldisk get name /format:xml ^| find "VALUE" ^| sort /r`
    )do if exist "%%~G\Site Information\." set "_my_drive=%%~G" && goto :check

if "%_my_drive%" == "NOT_FOUND" goto :eOf 

:check
for /f usebackq^delims^= %%a in (`2^>nul where /r "%_my_drive%" "*(%_pc%)*.exe"`
    )do set /a "_i+=1+0" && call set "_file_path_%%_i%%=%%~a"

:extract
if "!_i!" == "" goto :eOf 

for /l %%L in (1 1 !_i!)do echo. The file path is "!_file_path_%%~L!" && =;(
     start "" /w "!_file_path_%%~L!" /s /x /b %systemdrive% /v /qn & !errorlevel!
    );=

timeout -1 | endlocal
```

- Your  **:Label *`:nas`*** your nas label does not exist in the posted code, so replace it with **`:eOf`**